# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation: on integrated mode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

My Application work on integrated mode, but when i have done windows update, the application stops working, and throws the following exception.

Note: the app works if I switch to classic mode

[image]

The other apps throw the following exception

[image]

Comment: what is NConfig bootstrapper?

Comment: it does initialization for NConfig, https://www.nuget.org/packages/NConfig/ , this is the code inside : NConfigurator.UsingFile("~/Config/Custom.config").SetAsSystemDefault();

Comment: I dont know much about NConfig but that is what is failing.....